# Using Tensorflow's inference graph in Unity

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, tensorflow, machine-learning

First, let me clarify somethings, I don't know python.
I am currently working on my final year project and I needed a good Object detection technique, after trying many methods (color threshold, Haar-Classifiers), I stumbled around tensorflow, found myself a good tutorial, followed it and got the detector I want.
The problem:
I need and I want to work on Unity, Unity only supports C#.
I found an asset called TensorflowSharp but didn't know how to use it. The fact is I don't want to train on Unity, I trained on python I just need to use the "frozen inference graph" (as named in the tutorial) in unity to detect the object I want.

Please, I have to present in a month, any help is appreciated.

Comment: [This is not what StackOverflow is for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Also, generally when writing texts you should proof read them multiple times, because your text does not make sense at all. For example: *"I don't know python [...] I trained on python"* or *"I need and I want to work on Unity [...] The fact is I don't want to train on Unity"*.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know python, I followed a tutorial and trained it (what doesn't make sense here?) and for the Unity part, my whole project is on Unity I can't change platforms now. "I don't want to train on Unity (I mean train the detector) because I already trained it I just need to use the outputed graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at my [TFClassify-Unity](https://github.com/Syn-McJ/TFClassify-Unity) example. It uses trained model from official Tensorflow repo, but you can try your own by renaming its extension from '.pb' to '.bytes' and replacing default one with it.

Comment: I am trying to do the same for object detection. The app I took used mobilenet ssd model and it works. However, when I use my own custom tensorflow graph, it is not doing any detection. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you use your own tf graph then I suspect that input and output names of the graph will be different, you'll need to change them. Not sure if any changes in code are necessary though. If your model works with google's android example, you might try to port the code from java to c# directly.